# Visual Studio - Web Browser Project not displaying webpage when installed on computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

Thank you for taking a look.

So in Visual Studio I built a Web Browser. When I use the Debugger, my Browser works and display's all web pages. However, when I build a Setup Exe for the project and install it on my local machine, the browser does not display the home page. Does anybody have an idea of why this is?

[Screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIPp6.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi. Can you run the project on visual studio to access the web page？